# CSS: two colums (fixed/fluid) - same height

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

How can I do this:

- left column, fixed width, background say yellow
- main column, rest of the screen

main column will contain text of indefinite length, and I want the left column to be as high as the main no matter what the contents are. No header, no footer, just the screen split in two but the left **must** fill up all the space the main takes. No JavaScript.

Can this (very basic layout) be done **without** tricks like background images or absurd margin values? I'm trying to move on from the despised table approach, but so far I'm seeing that CSS only layouts always require some trickery even to do the easiest things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically the answer to the question "can this be done without tricks" is: No.

Answer (score 2):

I usually have two divs:  the outer one would contain the sidebar content that I want to have the same height as the main column, and the inner div would be the main column.

```
-----------------------------
|      -------------------- |
|      |                  | |
|      |                  | |
|      |                  | |
|      -------------------- |
-----------------------------
```

This way, the inner/main div forces the outer/sidebar div to be the same height as the inner/main.  Just `float:right` the inner/main div, set the outer/sidebar div to be `width:100%`, and specify that the inner/main div has a left margin, to allow for the sidebar, e.g. `margin-left:20%`.

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    --main content--
  </div>
  --sidebar content--
</div>
```

**Update:**  sorry, I had the sidebar content shown in the wrong place.  It should be *below* the inner/main div so that the inner/main div shows up alongside it to the right when it is floated.  Example CSS:

```
div.outer {
  width: 100%;
}

div.inner {
  margin-left: 20%; /* width of sidebar */
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: Can't get this to show what I need, can you provide an example of the style sheet?

Comment: I think that you'd want to add:
    height:100%;

To div.inner as well.

Comment: I doubt this works. The width=100% will punch the outer div below inner. You'll need more than this.

Comment: You're right, dland:  the sidebar/outer content does show up to the left of the inner/main content, but it's also shoved below it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a QUICK mockup. The main column fills up horizontally as you use it. You could set the main column width if you know the left column width already.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#leftCol
{
width:350px;
height:100%;
float:left;
background-color:#FFFF33;
}
#mainCol
{
width:53%;
height:100%;
float:left;
background-color:#CC0033;
}
#wrapper
{
width:100%;
}
.clearFix
{
clear:both;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="leftCol">tfgsrrtgrt

</div>
<div id="mainCol">gtrgdrtgthdyhtyhtyhydthtr

</div>
<div class="clearFix"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: note that if the browser width is restricted, mainCol will wrap underneath leftCol, which may be undesirable

Comment: Correct. Forgot about that. Then we'll need a min-width in there somewhere...

Perhaps in the #wrapper or #mainCol?